# Website Header That Resizes

Tags: html, css

I found and modified this basic bit of CSS to create top, left and side sections of my page.

```
.top {
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:250px;
    left:0; right:0;
    height:34px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2
}
.left {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:0; bottom: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background:#b41601;
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:250px;
    left:0; top:100px; right:0; bottom:0;
}
```

The left section is an accordion menu which is all sorted.  I would like the top to be a header that has just a plain colour background with some text as a title.

My problem is that when I resize the window the title squishes in and overlaps into the main section.

Is there a better way to get what I need?

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning for layout?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: thanks for the link.  I'll look into that.  This was the first method that I found and it is becoming clear that there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

Look in to the `@media` css rule , if the width goes below a certain value the webpage would respond to that, also its common in most browsers css3 is now a standard in most major browsers, even Mobile devices , It responds to either resizing or just a small display

Comment: Also the link to a resource that would help: [link](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwjA3LWz5tPIAhWBVRQKHfMiCRU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Fcss3_intro.asp&usg=AFQjCNHtc6UEsNPC7gdyG2x9j0bR1tFrPg&sig2=k8Zc7hSylUPmhFOz9fZ4BQ&bvm=bv.105454873,d.d24)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Sorry , Im not a regular here I just answer questions while im waiting for answers myself

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'll look into this tomorrow morning.

Comment: Upvote because this has taught me a fair bit.  I've already been using W3schools for a while but reading about @media has been instructive while not being entirely applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this must be the solution of your problem.

```css
.top{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
    background:aliceblue;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
.down{
    margin-top:25px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.left{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:29%;
    border-right:1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
.main{
     position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <h>HEADER</h>
</div>
<div class="down">
    <div class="left">Left Cont</div>
    <div class="main">Main Cont</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the code from Shudhansh, but it caused a few problems with the layout I'm trying to achieve.

I decided to start from scratch with something far simpler that I found while exploring the [w3schools.com CSS Float guide](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

Here is what I have used and so far it's working great.

```
.top{
    margin-left:250px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#b41601;
    background-color:#F2F2F2
}
.left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:100%;
    background:#b41601; 
}
.main{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:250px;
    text-align:center;
}
```